# When K8S writer env to docker? Is there a way to get real HOSTNAME or POST_NAME from dockerfile?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

My senerio is in dockfile, read env HOSTNAME and check value to do different work (before ENTRYPOIONT).

But during my work, i found HOSTNAME env is NOT writer by K8S like: **HOSTNAME=09729c381246**

so i think the real HOSTNAME is after ENTRYPOIONT run, K8S set the HOSTNAME and POST_NAME from deployment file.

**Is there a way to get real HOSTNAME or POST_NAME from dockerfile?**

thanks,

-Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The host name is potentially different each time a new container is created from the image, and the default naming scheme will be different in Kubernetes and plain Docker.  There's no way to know at image-build time what the **hostname**(1) eventually will be.